# Selecting the min from groups in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas Series that looks like this

```
>>> print(x)
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     9
9     6
10    3
11    5
12    7
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

I want to find the minimum value from each group of numbers that are not zero, I may not be explaining this great so I would like the output to look like this

```
>>> print(result)
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    3
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `shift`ing `cumsum` trick, then call `GroupBy.transform`:

```
u = x.eq(0)
x.groupby(u.ne(u.shift()).cumsum()).transform('min')

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @piRSquared obnoxious is subjective, you should consider posting it :)

Comment: Wow, did I waste some time on this one.  Don't even know why.

Comment: @piRSquared Slow afternoon? :D

Comment: I could've picked other questions.  I just wanted something with this one to click.  So I kept playing and playing.  I'm done now.  Back to work and then lunch.

Comment: @piRSquared It's nice! Out of curiosity, is `njit` the same as `jit` with `nopython=True`? I've seen these used in various contexts, and the general thread seems to indicate they are equivalent, but I thought I'd get your 2c.

Comment: Uh-oh... feeling an `itertools.groupby` solution coming on.

Comment: @piRSquared Uh, better go grab lunch before you change your mind :P

Answer (score 3):

#### `for` and Numba

I want to use a `for` loop but speed it up with Numba

- Yes: this is a `for` loop and not very pretty
- No: it is **not** slow because I use Numba (-:

---

#### Imports

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
```

#### Define Function

```
@njit
def f(x):
    y = []
    z = []
    for a in x:
        if not y:
            y.append(a)
            z.append(0)
        else:
            if (y[-1] == 0) ^ (a == 0):
                y.append(a)
                z.append(z[-1] + 1)
            else:
                y[-1] = min(y[-1], a)
                z.append(z[-1])
    return np.array(y)[np.array(z)]
```

#### Use Function

```
pd.Series(f(x.to_numpy()), x.index)

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    3
dtype: int64
```

---

#### `itertools.groupby`

[Credit to room 6 for the assist.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46484273#46484273)

```
from itertools import groupby, repeat

def repeat_min(x):
    for _, group in groupby(x, key=bool):
        group = list(group)
        minval = min(group)
        yield from repeat(minval, len(group))

pd.Series([*repeat_min(x)], x.index)

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    3
dtype: int64
```